# What happened to Eric after the Dauntless invasion simulator?

Tags: plot-explanation, divergent

**Eric**, as we all know, did Dauntless initiation with **Four** (this is in ***Divergent***) and Eric ended up with the leadership role after Four backed out of it.

Eric was in touch with **Jeanine Mathews** while a Dauntless and had plotted an attack against **Abnegation**. To do this, the **Erudite** had a serum that allowed for a simulated battle (just like the fear landscape).

After the battle, Eric was one of the few that didn't actually get the serum because he gave it out.

Where was he and where did he go *after* the invasion?
I have no idea, I have read the first book and watched the first movie, but nothing suggests that he was still around.

***Where did he go?***

Comment: I haven't read the books, but if you continue watching the movies, he does resurface later.

Comment: Ahhhh ok, is it ok if you put that into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

He was there when the attack took place as he was the one that stopped four and tris in their tracks. He did this because he thought that Four couldn't hear him so called him weak and basically dissed him. Then as Eric walked away he turned back and got the impression that Four was not implicated by the serum. He then held a gun to his head and said 'say goodbye *sshole', at which point tris perks up an sais 'goodbye' and holds her gun up. It then turns into a gun circle with people pointing guns at each other. Basically, Eric gets shot and they run off and tris gets shot then they get caught. So I'm guessing that Sric was around the abnegation sight making sure all was going to plan.